# how to draw AWS services specific diagrams?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to present my AWS based system architecture. Drawings and presentations, etc.
I am looking for the stencils, icons corresponding to AWS services.

Any ideas where I can find the AWS specific assets to represent a lambda or Dynamo or ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an official set of AWS powerpoint assets here: https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/icons/

Additionally, one tool that I like to use to build isometric architecture diagrams is https://cloudcraft.co

Answer (score 2):

I tried and played with some tools but my suggestion is to use [Altostra Designer](https://app.altostra.com/playground?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=first_phase&utm_medium=qnalink) to do so, it is free and not required any authentication.